# Error when exporting dataframe to csv file due to a nested dataframe

Tags: json, r, csv, dataframe, nested

I am trying to write a data frame in `R` to `csv` file, however it was returning to following error:

> Error in if (inherits(X[[j]], "data.frame") && ncol(xj) > 1L)
>                X[[j]] <- as.matrix(X[[j]]) : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

```
library("jsonlite")
setwd("~/Thesis/LaLiga")
file <- file("m1.json")
data <- fromJSON(file)
eventData <- as.data.frame(data)
write.csv(eventData, file = "m1.csv")
```

I think it is because I have problems with a nested dataframe but I am not able to solve it.

Contents of the dataframe:

```
'data.frame':   1733 obs. of  22 variables:
 $ url                                          : Factor w/ 1 level "http://omo.akamai.opta.net/?feed_type=f24_packed&game_id=819665": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ data.bin_ver                                 : int  7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
 $ data.Games.Game..attributes.id               : int  819665 819665 819665 819665 819665 819665 819665 819665 819665 819665 ...
 $ data.Games.Game..attributes.competition_id   : Factor w/ 1 level "23": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ data.Games.Game..attributes.season_id        : int  2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 ...
 $ data.Games.Game..attributes.home_team_id     : int  855 855 855 855 855 855 855 855 855 855 ...
 $ data.Games.Game..attributes.away_team_id     : int  176 176 176 176 176 176 176 176 176 176 ...
 $ data.Games.Game..attributes.matchday         : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ data.Games.Game..attributes.game_date.locale : Factor w/ 1 level "2015-08-23T21:00:00.000Z": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ data.Games.Game..attributes.game_date.utc    : Factor w/ 1 level "2015-08-23T19:00:00.000Z": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ data.Games.Game..attributes.type             : Factor w/ 1 level "COMP": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ data.Games.Game..attributes.home_team_name   : Factor w/ 1 level "Levante": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ data.Games.Game..attributes.homeNameObj.name : Factor w/ 1 level "Levante": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ data.Games.Game..attributes.homeNameObj.abbr : Factor w/ 1 level "LEV": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ data.Games.Game..attributes.away_team_name   : Factor w/ 1 level "Celta de Vigo": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ data.Games.Game..attributes.awayNameObj.name : Factor w/ 1 level "Celta de Vigo": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ data.Games.Game..attributes.awayNameObj.short: Factor w/ 1 level "Celta Vigo": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ data.Games.Game..attributes.awayNameObj.abbr : Factor w/ 1 level "CEL": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ data.Games.Game.Event..attributes            :'data.frame':  1733 obs. of  16 variables:
  ..$ id       : int  33709962 546849711 1429613613 1411119420 1136189326 1531836827 1333642811 1063160028 1557105400 620585007 ...
  ..$ event_id : int  1 1 2 2 3 4 5 667 1030 6 ...
  ..$ type_id  : chr  "34" "34" "32" "32" ...
  ..$ period_id: chr  "16" "16" "1" "1" ...
  ..$ min      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ sec      : int  0 0 0 0 1 2 5 6 6 7 ...
  ..$ player_id: chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
  ..$ team_id  : chr  "855" "176" "176" "855" ...
  ..$ outcome  : chr  "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
  ..$ x        : num  0 0 0 0 50.2 53.2 32.1 74.1 25.9 71.7 ...
  ..$ y        : num  0 0 0 0 48.2 43.9 75.6 71.2 28.8 76.9 ...
  ..$ assist   : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
  ..$ keypass  : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
  ..$ timestamp: chr  "2015-08-23T20:08:30.000" "2015-08-23T20:08:00.000" "2015-08-23T21:08:01.000" "2015-08-23T21:08:01.000" ...
  ..$ TimeStamp:'data.frame':   1733 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ locale: chr  "2015-08-23T20:10:30.000Z" "2015-08-23T20:20:00.000Z" "2015-08-23T21:00:01.000Z" "2015-08-23T21:00:01.000Z" ...
  .. ..$ utc   : chr  "2015-08-23T18:10:30.000Z" "2015-08-23T18:20:00.000Z" "2015-08-23T19:00:01.000Z" "2015-08-23T19:00:01.000Z" ...
  ..$ version  :'data.frame':   1733 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ lo: int  1325465600 1325465600 1325465600 1325465600 1325465600 1325465600 1325465600 1325465600 1325465600 1325465600 ...
  .. ..$ hi: num  3.92e+09 1.60e+09 4.61e+08 4.20e+09 2.17e+09 ...
 $ data.Games.Game.Event.Q                      :List of 1733
  ..$ :'data.frame':    7 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  7 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int  1414473052 1475463452 301508309 849544471 149684682 1895881029 1887752331
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr  "44" "194" "30" "227" ...
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr  "1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5" "5825" "71679, 105525, 77039, 5825, 48336, 87802, 89592, 54224, 169148, 108991, 175946, 61789, 11601, 130026, 165375, 109702, 26768, 89"| __truncated__ "0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    7 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  7 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int  1338495296 955688128 310905186 960647069 1031256143 2003897885 1248394807
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr  "44" "30" "130" "131" ...
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr  "1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5" "106539, 76508, 114128, 54806, 55117, 61559, 56624, 55509, 40270, 48854, 86173, 100263, 153269, 82970, 86151, 86152, 199319, 109"| __truncated__ "4" "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  1 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int 1844078223
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr "127"
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr "Right to Left"
  ..$ :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  1 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int 384835430
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr "127"
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr "Left to Right"
  ..$ :'data.frame':    7 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  7 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int  1222175736 964441814 1966229450 1246587790 831909528 2135938019 1704331732
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr  "140" "278" "56" "141" ...
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr  "53.2" "" "Center" "43.9" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    6 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  6 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int  440748943 342069373 1316765810 247701475 2065656020 247659384
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr  "141" "1" "140" "212" ...
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr  "75.0" "" "28.0" "33.9" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    7 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  7 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int  1140613619 1176574483 2031068751 1304837096 1038663926 1457575030 594954991
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr  "212" "140" "141" "213" ...
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr  "40.3" "70.5" "75.7" "0.0" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int  224071519 1592808165 1308224879
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr  "286" "56" "233"
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr  "" "Center" "1030"
  ..$ :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int  1306816 1425574017 1552769354
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr  "233" "285" "56"
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr  "667" "" "Back"
  ..$ :'data.frame':    7 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  7 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int  904721300 1858873635 433599825 2040593266 1600533458 1471827978 371702978
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr  "56" "140" "212" "3" ...
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr  "Center" "80.5" "9.9" "" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    5 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  5 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int  344987377 1619141634 1160638395 870138983 274021407
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr  "213" "212" "141" "140" ...
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr  "2.7" "9.7" "96.9" "82.0" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    5 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  5 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int  287115671 1846630319 1074878236 499203792 62586170
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr  "141" "56" "213" "140" ...
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr  "89.6" "Left" "4.9" "87.3" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    5 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  5 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int  1936771158 1672430839 1090588419 472560782 1546125236
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr  "213" "141" "56" "140" ...
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr  "0.6" "96.2" "Left" "93.4" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    8 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  8 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int  434724282 2003735707 1032719610 742492652 222300817 1436852800 1825595116 978006763
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr  "213" "141" "140" "1" ...
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr  "4.4" "34.2" "79.7" "" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    6 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  6 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int  810722989 1370803542 1141526394 2144935301 720113620 814858236
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr  "13" "152" "285" "265" ...
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    6 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  6 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int  1281814385 804659695 1218768819 1054581520 187921236 1303762440
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr  "233" "56" "265" "152" ...
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr  "3" "Center" "" "" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    2 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  2 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int  1297254880 831174078
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr  "144" "56"
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr  "61" "Center"
  ..$ :'data.frame':    8 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  8 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int  973607680 908340441 710050026 896654037 1547924239 804052848 747152828 774222676
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr  "233" "56" "147" "146" ...
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr  "4" "Center" "39.5" "86.7" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    4 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  4 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int  1961823391 1792756979 36047128 183775027
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr  "239" "233" "56" "94"
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr  "" "11" "Back" ""
  ..$ :'data.frame':    5 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  5 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int  1260744541 402741924 1745330254 751087084 660635432
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr  "213" "140" "141" "212" ...
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr  "6.1" "70.1" "42.3" "54.4" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    7 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  7 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int  1694767093 1107697057 877749219 1668064963 425795808 973286328 642707556
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr  "1" "212" "140" "213" ...
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr  "" "51.4" "69.8" "5.6" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int  504376903 1782091272 1481090659
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr  "285" "56" "233"
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr  "" "Back" "13"
  ..$ :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int  1065575050 781377047 1397470211
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr  "56" "233" "286"
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr  "Right" "6" ""
  ..$ :'data.frame':    7 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  7 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int  1575727527 1319497881 1962678558 871721178 344072861 2106452116 817682289
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr  "56" "141" "168" "212" ...
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr  "Center" "28.5" "" "20.3" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    6 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  6 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int  1026592213 105409358 407081616 1936025455 521838415 1460844762
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr  "212" "213" "56" "141" ...
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr  "7.6" "4.3" "Back" "57.9" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    0 obs. of  0 variables
  ..$ :'data.frame':    6 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  6 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int  581063835 27641279 665538423 1781913283 753584849 644570511
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr  "240" "141" "213" "212" ...
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr  "" "28.5" "5.3" "16.0" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    5 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  5 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int  1087342075 689978467 1841197266 1176463502 829050058
  .. .. ..$ qualifier_id: chr  "212" "141" "140" "56" ...
  .. .. ..$ value       : chr  "24.5" "57.6" "9.6" "Back" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    5 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ @attributes:'data.frame':  5 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ id          : int  1625483273 190200997 1347733551 940921513
```

The problem is that I especially need the data from the nested data frame. It has the same number of rows as the original data frame with no missing values. Is there somebody who knows how to handle this nested data frame so that I convert it towards a csv file?

Here below, is an example of the json format.

```
{
"url": "http://omo.akamai.opta.net/?feed_type=f24_packed&game_id=459490",
"data": {
    "bin_ver": 3,
    "Games": {
        "Game": {
            "@attributes": {
                "id": 459490,
                "competition_id": "21",
                "season_id": 2012,
                "home_team_id": 456,
                "away_team_id": 129,
                "matchday": 1,
                "compObj": {
                    "type": "COMP"
                },
                "home_team_name": "Atalanta",
                "homeNameObj": {
                    "name": "Atalanta",
                    "short": "Atalanta",
                    "abbr": "ATA"
                },
                "away_team_name": "Lazio",
                "awayNameObj": {
                    "name": "Lazio",
                    "abbr": "LAZ"
                }
            },
            "Event": [
                {
                    "@attributes": {
                        "id": 817366983,
                        "event_id": 1,
                        "type_id": "34",
                        "period_id": "16",
                        "min": 0,
                        "sec": 0,
                        "player_id": "0",
                        "team_id": "129",
                        "outcome": "1",
                        "x": 0,
                        "y": 0,
                        "assist": "0",
                        "keypass": "0",
                        "timestamp": "2012-08-26T19:08:36.000",
                        "TimeStamp": {
                            "locale": "2012-08-26T19:35:36.000Z",
                            "utc": "2012-08-26T17:35:36.000Z"
                        }
                    },
                    "Q": [
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "id": 453619531,
                                "qualifier_id": "30",
                                "value": "38479, 17886, 52049, 11871, 18414, 52498, 45156, 49822, 5155, 48863, 13501, 8278, 5857, 13530, 49696, 94239, 51950, 116120, 16106, 78272, 28592"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "id": 100135486,
                                "qualifier_id": "130",
                                "value": "7"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "id": 1426972438,
                                "qualifier_id": "59",
                                "value": "22, 29, 19, 24, 20, 3, 87, 8, 11, 15, 6, 1, 5, 9, 10, 16, 18, 23, 27, 39, 99"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "id": 495685481,
                                "qualifier_id": "227",
                                "value": "0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "id": 1999694729,
                                "qualifier_id": "131",
                                "value": "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "id": 1965758595,
                                "qualifier_id": "44",
                                "value": "1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "id": 1217628093,
                                "qualifier_id": "194",
                                "value": "13501"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "@attributes": {
                        "id": 230703132,
                        "event_id": 1,
                        "type_id": "34",
                        "period_id": "16",
                        "min": 0,
                        "sec": 0,
                        "player_id": "0",
                        "team_id": "456",
                        "outcome": "1",
                        "x": 0,
                        "y": 0,
                        "assist": "0",
                        "keypass": "0",
                        "timestamp": "2012-08-26T19:08:38.000",
                        "TimeStamp": {
                            "locale": "2012-08-26T19:35:38.000Z",
                            "utc": "2012-08-26T17:35:38.000Z"
                        }
                    },
                    "Q": [
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "id": 1835492395,
                                "qualifier_id": "30",
                                "value": "18500, 7216, 27702, 18362, 13663, 38476, 74375, 21140, 48850, 55831, 49417, 7454, 40141, 37911, 60999, 51892, 8391, 86125, 17448, 18502, 10718, 48256"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "id": 2140420416,
                                "qualifier_id": "130",
                                "value": "6"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "id": 763819661,
                                "qualifier_id": "194",
                                "value": "7216"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "id": 211854953,
                                "qualifier_id": "44",
                                "value": "1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "id": 1852739778,
                                "qualifier_id": "227",
                                "value": "0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "id": 1991110165,
                                "qualifier_id": "131",
                                "value": "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "id": 1185192346,
                                "qualifier_id": "59",
                                "value": "47, 6, 28, 21, 3, 13, 7, 88, 19, 11, 10, 5, 9, 16, 23, 25, 32, 33, 44, 77, 78, 99"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "@attributes": {
                        "id": 71166703,
                        "event_id": 2,
                        "type_id": "32",
                        "period_id": "1",
                        "min": 0,
                        "sec": 0,
                        "player_id": "0",
                        "team_id": "129",
                        "outcome": "1",
                        "x": 0,
                        "y": 0,
                        "assist": "0",
                        "keypass": "0",
                        "timestamp": "2012-08-26T19:08:56.000",
                        "TimeStamp": {
                            "locale": "2012-08-26T19:46:56.000Z",
                            "utc": "2012-08-26T17:46:56.000Z"
                        }
                    },
                    "Q": [
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "id": 1539766623,
                                "qualifier_id": "127",
                                "value": "Left to Right"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },  {
                    "@attributes": {
                        "id": 2088668537,
                        "event_id": 3,
                        "type_id": "1",
                        "period_id": "1",
                        "min": 0,
                        "sec": 1,
                        "player_id": "48850",
                        "team_id": "456",
                        "outcome": "1",
                        "x": 50.6,
                        "y": 49.3,
                        "assist": "0",
                        "keypass": "0",
                        "timestamp": "2012-08-26T19:08:58.000",
                        "TimeStamp": {
                            "locale": "2012-08-26T19:46:58.000Z",
                            "utc": "2012-08-26T17:46:58.000Z"
                        }
                    },
                    "Q": [
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "id": 85939674,
                                "qualifier_id": "141",
                                "value": "48.8"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "id": 1825905114,
                                "qualifier_id": "140",
                                "value": "49.6"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "id": 1433042637,
                                "qualifier_id": "212",
                                "value": "1.1"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "id": 613763324,
                                "qualifier_id": "213",
                                "value": "3.5"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "id": 2046838408,
                                "qualifier_id": "56",
                                "value": "Back"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

Comment: You have a dataframe in which are embedded more other dataframes. You should first unwrap the inner dataframes to be able to save the data as a csv, I believe.

Comment: Please post content of json in body of question so we can help reproduce.

Comment: I posted the json content for one event (one row) @Parfait.

Comment: That does not seem to be all of the json. Where is url? ids? competition fields?

Comment: I now uploaded the beginning of the json file which contains the url , competion id, formations and the first ball event @Parfait

Comment: Unfortunately, json is not valid as it may not be closing properly at end. So still incomplete. Test with online json validators.

Comment: @RubendeVries can you guid me how can convert you data from ".csv". to .json from scratch ?